# find the closest next hour

Tags: php

how can I find the next closest hour in php

so for example if current time is 4:15 the next hour will be 5, etc

```
$dateString = 'Tue, 13 Mar 2012 04:48:34 -0400';
$date = new DateTime( $dateString );
echo $date->format( 'H:i:s' );
```

gives me the time from the string and I want to expand on that and get the next closest hour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supply any eligible date() to:

```
function roundToNextHour($dateString) {
    $date = new DateTime($dateString);
    $minutes = $date->format('i');
    if ($minutes > 0) {
        $date->modify("+1 hour");
        $date->modify('-'.$minutes.' minutes');
    }
    return $date;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
$nextHour = (intval($date->format('H'))+1) % 24;
echo $nextHour; // 5
```

Answer (score 10):

Here we go:

```
<?php
    echo date("H:00",strtotime($date. " + 1hour "));
?>
```

Comment: I think this is the best one.

Comment: I agree, this should be accepted... it's so simple.

Answer (score 5):

Can you just take pieces (hours, minutes, seconds) and get the next hour?

```
$dateString = 'Tue, 13 Mar 2012 04:48:34 -0400';
$date = new DateTime( $dateString );

echo $date->format( 'H:i:s' );
echo "\n";

$nexthour = ($date->format('H') + ($date->format('i') > 0 || $date->format('s') > 0 ? 1 : 0)) % 24;
echo "$nexthour:00:00";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$dateString = 'Tue, 13 Mar 2012 04:48:34 -0400';

$date = new DateTime( $dateString );
$date->modify('+1 hour');

echo $date->format('H:i:s').PHP_EOL;

// OR

echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($dateString) + 60 * 60).PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 3):

As I just needed something similar (next full hour) here my solution:

```
$now = time();
$nextFullHour = date(DATE_ATOM, $now + (3600 - $now % 3600));
```

By replacing the `3600` e.g. with `60` you get the next full minute...
You can also replace the `$now` with any other timestamp if you do not need it relative to the current time.

Answer (score 1):

That is my solution:

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime();
$dateTime->add(new \DateInterval('PT1H'))
         ->setTime($dateTime->format('H'), '00');
```

Answer (score 1):

Nobody else used this one so I figured I'd drop it here, simplest one I saw above for an actual timestamp, not just the hour itself.

```
$now = ''; // empty uses current time, or you can insert a datetime string
$next_hour = date( 'Y-m-d H:00:00', strtotime( $now . ' +1 hour' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

try it for current time, if you need put second argument to date function

```
<?php echo date('H')+1; ?>
```

very nice stuff

Comment: Simple, short and effective.

Comment: If current hours = 24. Then next = 24 + 1 = 25

Answer (score 0):

One more:

```php
$current_datetime = new DateTimeImmutable();
$next_full_hour_datetime = $current_datetime
    ->modify(
        sprintf(
            '+%d seconds',
            3600 - ($current_datetime->getTimestamp() % 3600)
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to this party, but here's a more flexible function to round up a dateTime object by any interval in minutes. You pass in your dateTime object and a rounding interval in minutes, so for an hour you'd just pass in 60, etc.

```
    public function round_up_time( $datetime, $rounding_interval ) {
        // get total minutes from the start of the day
        $minutes = ( intval( $datetime->format( 'H' ) ) * 60 ) + ( intval( $datetime->format( 'i' ) ) );
        // round up the minutes based on the interval we are rounding to
        $rounded_minutes = ( intval( $minutes / $rounding_interval ) + 1 ) * $rounding_interval;
        // reset our dateTime to the very start of the day
        $datetime->setTime( 0, 0 );
        // then increase the dateTime by the rounded minutes value
        $datetime->modify( '+ ' . $rounded_minutes . ' minutes' );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the next closest full hour in DateTime:

```
$date = new DateTime('+1 hour'); //set the next hour
$date->setTime($date->format('H'), '00', '00'); //keep the next hour, set minutes to 00 and seconds to 00
```

Answer (score -1):

simple like this :

```
$nextHourTS = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:00:00',strtotime('+1 hours')));
$nextHourDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$nextHourTS);
```

strtotime is relative to timezone, so keep this in mind.
have a good day !

Comment: Please provide only answers that add some new method. Answers featuring strtotime are already abundant in this post